# Is including scss files with @use deprecated?

Tags: css, import, sass

First of all, hello everyone.

I get an error when I want to include scss files using @use in my project. There are no errors in the videos I watch on Youtube. I wonder if the inclusion of the scss file with @use is deprecated? I went with @import to include the scss files. Thank you in advance for the answer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yL4g.png)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error ?

Comment: @Seblor I'm attaching a picture of the error right away.

Comment: Well have you read the error (which is actually a warning) ? The issue is not a deprecation of `@use` but of the division operation.

Comment: Please read [ask], where it says, “DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question”

Comment: Hmm. I get it. I'm a novice at sharing. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

It is the other way round: @import is deprecated and will be replaced by @use.

The warning you get says it all: Using the divis '/' for divisions is deprecated, you should use math.div(a/b).

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 4.6. Unfortunately, the "/" operation is done that way. 
There are too many operations with "/". I guess I need to fix them all one by one.

Comment: @MusaYazlik you can get more informations in this Github Issue : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/34051

Comment: Yeah, that's a common problem. You can always go fast and break things using a framework - but someday you will have to return and repair everything. It's called "technical debt", and there is no way escaping it.